# Create a generic response item for java

Tags: java, android, variables, generics, response

This is my question: my english is not the best.

Create a generic response item for java.

```
public class GenericResponse(){

  private "generic class" a;

}
```

i need in the constructor method setting the "class" type for the variable generic.

```
GenericResponse(t.class){
   a = t.class;
}
```

Comment: You can't programmatically set the generic type for an instance of a generic class.  It must be known at compile time, and the type of the generic for that instance will never change for the lifetime of that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get to that is named Generic Data Type in java... 
and it can looks like:

```
public class GenericTypeData<T> {

    private final T a;

    public GenericTypeData(T a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          GenericTypeData<String> string = new GenericTypeData<String>("am a String");
          GenericTypeData<Integer> intType = new GenericTypeData<Integer>(122);
    }

}
```